# XmlNode.Value пустой, хотя в innerText данные есть

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Здравствуйте, есть xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<yml_catalog date="2015-11-12 11:57:22">
  <shop>
    <name>Интернет-магазин</name>
    <company>НазваниеОрганизации</company>
    <url>http://example.com</url>
  </shop>
</yml_catalog>
```

Пытаюсь получить значение элемента `name`, но свойство Value возвращает пустую строку.

```
// priceList - объект класса XmlDocument в который уже загружен XML
XmlNode yml_catalog = priceList.SelectSingleNode("yml_catalog");
string priceDate = yml_catalog.Attributes["date"].Value;
XmlNode shop = yml_catalog.SelectSingleNode("shop/name");
string shopName = shop.Value; //пустой
string innerText= shop.innerText; // Интернет-магазин
```

Как получить значение элемента `name` через `Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чисто технически, текст "Интернет-магазин" лежит не непосредственно в самой ноде `<name>`. Вместо этого в элемент `<name>` вложена еще одна нода, с типом Text. И вот у нее уже Value - "Интернет-магазин".

Его можно выбрать напрямую:

```
XmlNode shopNameText = yml_catalog.SelectSingleNode("shop/name/text()");
string shopName = shopNameText.Value; // Интернет-магазин
```

или через родительский элемент:

```
XmlNode shop = yml_catalog.SelectSingleNode("shop/name");
string shopName = shop.FirstChild.Value; // Интернет-магазин
```

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
XmlNode shop = yml_catalog.SelectSingleNode("shop/name/text()");
string shopName = shop.Value;
```